# <%= will_paginate @posts %> not showing links in production(Heroku)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, will-paginate

I am having trouble with the will_paginate gem as the paginate links are not showing up in Heroku production. It is working perfectly in the local environment.

General Information

- I have 11 posts in the production database
- heroku logs doesn't seem to give me any errors.

Gemfile

```
gem 'rails', '3.2.3'

group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
end

group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails'
  gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby
  gem 'less'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

  gem 'jquery-rails'
  gem 'opentok'
  gem 'redcarpet', '1.17.2'
  gem 'will_paginate', "~> 3.0.3"
  gem 'bcrypt-ruby', :require => "bcrypt"
```

Environment.rb

```
require 'will_paginate/array'
```

Posts_Controller.rb

```
def index
  @posts = Post.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10, :order => 'created_at DESC')

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # index.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @posts }
  end
end
```

Index.html.erb(Posts)

```
<%= will_paginate @posts %>
<%= render 'post' %>
```

_Post.html.erb

```
<% @posts.each do |post| %>
<h1><%= link_to post.title, post_path(post) %></h1>
<p>Posted On: <%= post.created_at %></p>
<p>
    <%= markdown(post.body) %>
</p>
<% if admin? %>
    <%= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(post), :class => "btn" %>
    <%= link_to "Destroy", post_path(post), :method => :delete, :class => :destroy %>
<% end %>
<hr/>
```

Please let me know if you need more information!

Comment: What does `heroku logs` show when you access this index?

Comment: Do you have posts in your production database?

Comment: I don't seem to get any errors in heroku logs. Yes, I created 11 posts in production.

Comment: so u have less then 10 post in production db)

Comment: Ah, I'm an idiot.  I fixed it by adding 12 posts in the production db.  I thought the links would show with just 11.  If you want to put that as an answer, i'll accept it. Thanks for the help!  Anyone know why it requires 12 when i have the per_page set to 10?